# 'origin' field not exist in SafeTransactionData

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

On this rest api Doc https://safe-transaction.gnosis.io the `SafeMultisigTransaction` Input type has property 'origin'  that's supposed to "give more information about the transaction".
This field is also described in this [official tutorial](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/tutorials/tutorial_tx_service_initiate_sign).

However, the `SafeTransactionData` type in `safe-core-sdk` does not have this property. Is the property no longer supported? is https://safe-transaction.gnosis.io the updated API doc?

Comment: On top of that, will the origin message be displayed on the web ui anywhere?
I was able to provide an origin through the rest api

Comment: `origin` property is not displayed anywhere in the UI

Comment: I released a new version including this fix

Answer (score 1):

The `origin` field is not included in the method `proposeTransaction()` from the `safe-service-client` (package inside the `safe-core-sdk` monorepo).

I'll create a GitHub issue to include it.

Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: Created here: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/issues/160